# Fitting age adjusted model in R

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to fit a logistic regression model in R but adjust for age only. How can this be done? I know there is a way to fit univariable logistic model using `gtsummary tbl_uvregression function`. Can we tweak this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

set.seed(100)

trialdata <- tibble(
  outcome = factor(rbinom(1000, 1, 0.10),
                   labels = c("No", "Yes")),
  age = floor(rnorm(1000, 16, 3)),
  score = floor(runif(1000, 30, 99)),
  school = factor(rbinom(1000, 1, 0.35),
                   labels = c("No", "Yes")),
  education = factor(rbinom(1000, 2, 0.20),
                  labels = c("Primary", "Secondary", "Tertiary"))

)

tbl_uv_ex1 <-
  trialdata %>%
  tbl_uvregression(
    method = glm,
    y = outcome,
    method.args = list(family = binomial),
    exponentiate = TRUE
  )

tbl_uv_ex1
```

Comment: why not `glm(outcome ~ age, family="binomial", data=trialdata)`?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, I mean to include all the variables in the model but adjust for age

Comment: An example would be 

glm(outcome ~ score+age, family="binomial", data=trialdata),

glm(outcome ~ school+age, family="binomial", data=trialdata),

Comment: still not clear on this.  You want to fit 3 separate models, each including age and one other predictor?  You could just do that ...  Can we have a little more context please?  Can you point us to an example?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand "including" a variable vs. "adjusting for" a variable.

Comment: In univariable model we look at the effect of each variable on the outcome what would then give us crude ORs. For this case I want to include each variable and adjust age in the model

Comment: Use the `tbl_uvregression(formula=)` argument. `formula = '{y} ~ {x} + age'`

Comment: It works as intended!

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg (or Moses), please post as answer ... (the answre makes it pretty clear that this is a `gtsummary`-package-specific question, not a general question about fitting GLMs ...

Comment: I will let @DanielD.Sjoberg post it then I accept it

Comment: I'm not at a computer. Anyone please feel free to post if you'd like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tbl_uvregression(formula=) argument. formula = '{y} ~ {x} + age'